# Problem with a query using contain(), order() and limit() in Cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have the two following associations :

AgendaDates `hasOne` ImageDescriptive

AgendaDates `hasMany` Photos

When I do this query :

```php
$dates = $this->AgendaDates
                        ->find()
                        ->order(['AgendaDates.date' => 'ASC'])
                        ->contain(['ImageDescriptive' => function ($q) { // AgendaDates hasOne ImageDescriptive
                            return $q->find('translations');
                        }])
                        ->limit(2);
```

I have the following error :

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'brigittepatient.AgendaDates.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**

The SQL query that returns an error is :

```sql
SELECT 
  FichiersI18n.id AS FichiersI18n__id, 
  FichiersI18n.locale AS FichiersI18n__locale, 
  FichiersI18n.model AS FichiersI18n__model, 
  FichiersI18n.foreign_key AS FichiersI18n__foreign_key, 
  FichiersI18n.field AS FichiersI18n__field, 
  FichiersI18n.content AS FichiersI18n__content 
FROM 
  fichiers_i18n FichiersI18n 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      (ImageDescriptive.id) 
    FROM 
      agenda_dates AgendaDates 
      LEFT JOIN fichiers ImageDescriptive ON (
        ImageDescriptive.model = 'AgendaDates' 
        AND ImageDescriptive.field = 'image_descriptive' 
        AND AgendaDates.id = ImageDescriptive.foreign_key
      ) 
    GROUP BY 
      ImageDescriptive.id 
    ORDER BY 
      AgendaDates.date ASC 
    LIMIT 
      2
  ) ImageDescriptive ON FichiersI18n.foreign_key = ImageDescriptive.id 
WHERE 
  FichiersI18n.model = 'Fichiers'
```

The strange thing is that when I do the same thing but with Photos (linked to AgendaDates by `hasMany` instead of `hasOne`) :

```php
$dates = $this->AgendaDates
                        ->find()
                        ->order(['AgendaDates.date' => 'ASC'])
                        ->contain(['Photos' => function ($q) { // AgendaDates hasMany Photos
                            return $q->find('translations');
                        }])
                        ->limit(2);
```

**I have no error** and the query looks like that :

```sql
SELECT 
  FichiersI18n.id AS FichiersI18n__id, 
  FichiersI18n.locale AS FichiersI18n__locale, 
  FichiersI18n.model AS FichiersI18n__model, 
  FichiersI18n.foreign_key AS FichiersI18n__foreign_key, 
  FichiersI18n.field AS FichiersI18n__field, 
  FichiersI18n.content AS FichiersI18n__content 
FROM 
  fichiers_i18n FichiersI18n 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      (Photos.id) 
    FROM 
      fichiers Photos 
    WHERE 
      (
        Photos.model = 'AgendaDates' 
        AND Photos.field = 'photos' 
        AND Photos.foreign_key in (5, 3)
      ) 
    GROUP BY 
      Photos.id
  ) Photos ON FichiersI18n.foreign_key = Photos.id 
WHERE 
  FichiersI18n.model = 'Fichiers'
```

I really don't understand why my cakephp query throws an error in the case of `hasOne` association but not in the case of `hasMany` association ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the query that causes it? Unless you modify it in a `beforeFind` listener, or if you have some custom query building for that `Diapo` association config, I don't see how grouping would slip in here. Check the stacktrace to figure from where it originates, also check Debug Kits's SQL log to see the exact query, that might give some hints.

Comment: @ndm I edited my question with the query concerned, but I'm still confused...

Comment: Maybe I should've started with asking what exactly you're having a problem with. Is it that you don't know what strict grouping is which is causing this error, or is it that you don't know why grouping unexpectedly ends up in your query? Looking at the SQL, certainly your query object must be manipulated further somewhere.

Comment: @ndm The problem seems to come from the fact that my (self-made) `AttachmentBehavior::beforeFind()` make `$query->find('translations');` to find translations of Diapo legends. When I comment this callback, the problem disappear. But I really don't know/understand the problem origin... and what to do to fix it (?)

Comment: I have to again ask what exactly it is that you do not understand. How the query ends up looking like this? Or what the `only_full_group_by` mode / strict grouping is, and how that query is incompatible with that mode?

Comment: @ndm I would say both ^^ but especially what is `only_full_group_by` and how the query is incompatible with it.

Comment: @ndm I have edited my question, if you could have a look ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Strict Grouping

The `only_full_group_by` mode requires that all fields in `SELECT`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` must be either functionally dependent (column `a` uniquely determines column `b`), or aggregates.

When grouping, not all values for a column in a group will necessarily be equal, imagine an `Articles hasMany Comments` relation, if you join in `Comments` and group by `Articles.id`, all columns of `Articles` can be determined by the `id` primary key column, the columns of `Comments` however cannot, there could be multiple different `Comments` column values per `Article.id`, something like this:

| Articles.id | Comments.created |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 2022-02-02 |

If you had such results, then MySQL wouldn't know which of the two different `Comments.created` values to pick from the group when asked to order by it, hence issuing a query that could produce such a result will throw an error.

When strict group by mode is disabled, then MySQL would be allowed to pick a value from the group basically at random, which makes the results unpredictable, which can be a problem. Using an aggegrate can fix that, for example `MIN(Comments.created)` to use the smallest date value from the groups.

You can find more on that topic in the docs, and generally all over the internet:

- **https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html**
- **https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html**

### hasMany vs hasOne

Your two queries produce different SQL, `hasMany` associations are always retrieved in a separate query, that is where you're calling the `translations` finder on, a separate query where no joining, ordering and limiting is happening, hence the grouping for the translations will not cause any problems since only the one field that is used for grouping is involved.

`hasOne` association are using joins by default, so a single query, hence here you're calling the `translations` finder on that single query, the one where you're doing the sorting and limiting, and that's where the clash between the grouping for the translations and the ordering that references a field from the group stems from.

### tl;dr

It should be possible to avoid this problem by using the `select` strategy for the translate behavior, which will then obtain the translations using the queried primary keys instead of a subquery where grouping is applied:

```php
$this->addBehavior('Translate', [
    'strategy' => 'select',
    // ...
]);
```

Using an `INNER` join for the `ImageDescriptive` association might possibly also fix the problem (that is in case the possible multiple `null` values that the query could produce are the source of the functional dependency problem), but it would of course change how records are queried when `null` values are involved.

Comment: Huge huge thanks ndm, you rock ! :)